# Multiple Image PDFs into a larger single page PDF

Tags: pdf, images, pdf-reader, cad, pdfcreator

I work with CAD drawings that have been segmented into multiple PDFs for a specific floor sections of a building.  I would like to CROP the unnecessary data and assemble the images into a single, same quality, large PDF file to make looking at the entire floor much easier.

I have tried looking at several different ways of doing this with ADOBE and NITRO but no success to date. This would be the reverse of what I have seen for answers concerning printing multiple pages to create a poster from a single image.  I have several "printed" images that need cropped and then "glued" together in a single larger image. Any suggestions?

Frank

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DTP Program to achieve this result. Create a new Document in the desired final size and place, crop the PDF files in this document. Then export this file as a new PDF. Free Software Scribus or proprietary Adobe InDesign are available for this task.